# Find and compare the last and the row before in a group it if it matches the criteria in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have a dataframe that contains game data. For this game 2 players play a 90 minute game. However the game can last longer than 90 minutes for various reasons. What I want is to find games that player 1 won after the 90th minute mark. So I'd like the compare the end score for a game that:
- lasted more than 90 minutes,
- Player 1 won
with the previous score for the time<90 minutes.

[image: games dataframe]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/15/5599929a88b1a266ad6476488094fccd-full.png))</sub>

```py
  # Games dataframe
  games = pd.DataFrame({'game_id': {0: 1,1: 1,2: 1,3: 2,4: 2,5: 3,6: 3,7: 
                     3,8: 4,9: 4,10: 4,11: 5,12: 5,13: 5},
                    'time': {0: 1,1: 45,2: 95,3: 56,4: 80,5: 1,6: 95,7: 
                     95,8: 96,9: 107,10: 108,11: 15,12: 95,13: 97},
                    'player 1': {0: 1,1: 1,2: 2,3: 1,4: 1,5: 0,6: 1,7: 2,8: 
                     0,9: 1,10: 2,11: 1,12: 1,13: 1},
                    'player 2': {0: 0,1: 1,2: 1,3: 0,4: 1,5: 1,6: 1,7: 1,8: 
                     1,9: 1,10: 1,11: 0,12: 1,13: 2}})

  # Find the rows with the ending scores of games
  a = games.drop_duplicates(["game_id"],keep='last')

  #Find games that player 1 wins and time>90
  b = games[((games["player 1"] - games["player 2"]) >0) (games["time"]>90)]
```

For example for game 1 Player 1 won at 95th minute before that the scores were even. Overall if the situation was a tie between 2 players before 90th minute or Player 1 was losing but after 90 minute mark the final situation is that Player 1 won. How can I filter this case ?

Comment: What happened in the 3rd game at 95th minute? Why are there two entries for the same minute?

Comment: In the same minute there were 2 goals scored by Player 1

Comment: I can't figure out quickly how to get what you're trying to do, but I suppose you might find the [tutorial on reshaping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
How about this?

```
endScores = games.loc[(games['time'] > 90) & (games['player 1'] > games['player 2'])].groupby('game_id').nth(-1)
beforeScores = games.loc[(games['time'] <= 90) & (games['player 1'] <= games['player 2'])].groupby('game_id').nth(-1)
compareGames = beforeScores.join(endScores, rsuffix='_end').dropna()
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I'm looking for the specific situations. For example if Player 1 was winning before 90th minute then it winning after 90th minute is not the case I want. The cases I'm looking for are : 1) if the game was a tie before 90 minute  mark and after 90th minute Player 1 won. 2) If Player 1 was losing before the 90 minute mark and won after 90th minute. Basically I'm looking for sth. that compares the end score with the score before 90th minute mark and filter the cases that player 1 won matching with the criterias I listed.

Comment: Gabriel this works great for most cases but what can be done about game_id 4. It does not state the scores before 90 minutes so we consider it to be 0-0 but after it on 108th minute  Player 1 scores a goal and wins. That case should be added to compareGames as well.

Comment: If you add the 0-0 scores for every game it should work.